# How to convert SQL query to Laravel eloquent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, builder

how can I convert my raw sql query to laravel query? I have issues with 'to_date' and tried many things.

This is my code:

```
select n_reserva,cod_hab_r1,cod_hab_r2,cod_hab_r3,fecha_reserva,fecha_entrada,fecha_salida,tour,dni_r,nombre,apellidos
from reservadas
join huespedes on huespedes.dni=reservadas.dni_r
where fecha_entrada=(select to_date(sysdate) from dual);
```

My suggest for laravel is this:

```
DB::table('reservadas')
->select('n_reserva','cod_hab_r1','cod_hab_r2','cod_hab_r3','fecha_reserva',
'fecha_entrada','fecha_salida','tour','dni_r','nombre','apellidos')
->join('huespedes','huespedes.dni','=','reservadas.dni_r')
->where('fecha_entrada','=',function($query){
        $query->from('dual')
        ->select(DB::raw("to_date(sysdate)"));
    })
->get();
```

SQL code works fine, so the problem is in the second one.

Comment: if u translate it to English will be easier to get helped

Comment: Instead of using `->get()`, use `->toSql()` and see the resulting SQL

Answer (score 0):

I mostly use an online converter to convert my raw SQL query to a query builder for example you can use the below website to convert your code from raw to query builder

https://sql2builder.github.io/

your query

```
select n_reserva,cod_hab_r1,cod_hab_r2,cod_hab_r3,fecha_reserva,fecha_entrada,fecha_salida,tour,dni_r,nombre,apellidos
from reservadas
join huespedes on huespedes.dni=reservadas.dni_r
where fecha_entrada=(select to_date(sysdate) from dual);
```

the output

```
DB::table('reservadas')
->select('n_reserva', 'cod_hab_r1', 'cod_hab_r2', 'cod_hab_r3', 'fecha_reserva', 'fecha_entrada', 'fecha_salida', 'tour', 'dni_r', 'nombre', 'apellidos')
->join('huespedes','huespedes.dni','=','reservadas.dni_r')
->where('fecha_entrada','=',function($query) {
    $query->from('dual')
        ->select(DB::raw("'to_date'(sysdate));
})
->get();
```